# Disable keyboard interaction with UWP app

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I am building a UWP application and I wish to disable the keyboard interaction with my application. This means my app should not in any way respond when any key on the keyboard is pressed.

Is this achievable? Can I selectively disable interaction with some keys like the Tab key etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [KeyboardDeliveryInterceptor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.input.keyboarddeliveryinterceptor) class for this. Couple of things to note with this:

1. You will need to declare restricted capability 'inputForegroundObservation' in your appxmanifest file:

```html
<Capabilities>
  <Capability Name="internetClient" />
  <rescap:Capability xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities" Name="inputForegroundObservation"/>
</Capabilities>
```

2. You cannot intercept keys selectively, but you can respond to particular intercepted keys in your code and respond with the desired action (e.g. move focus when the tab key is pressed):

```js
KeyboardDeliveryInterceptor interceptor = KeyboardDeliveryInterceptor.GetForCurrentView();
interceptor.IsInterceptionEnabledWhenInForeground = true;
interceptor.KeyUp += delegate(KeyboardDeliveryInterceptor sender, KeyEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.VirtualKey == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Tab)
    {
        // perform desired tab key action
    }
};
```

Comment: My use case is to disable the keyboard interaction with the Tab key and handle input from rest of the keys normally. 

So, if I intercept all keys using the KeyboardDeliveryInterceptor class the way you have mentioned, can I programmatically tell my app to handle input from all the other keys normally.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Capabilities>
     <Capability Name="internetClient" />
     <rescap:Capability xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities" Name="inputForegroundObservation"/>
</Capabilities>
```

Add permission as Stefan said above. After you add permission add below code.

```
Dispatcher.AcceleratorKeyActivated += Dispatcher_AcceleratorKeyActivated;

private void Dispatcher_AcceleratorKeyActivated(CoreDispatcher sender, AcceleratorKeyEventArgs args)
    {
        if(args.key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Tab)
        {
           args.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

The above code prevents the Tab button to perform any action. Hence, When the user presses Tab key no action will be performed.