# disable a specific hardware keyboard keys(e.g. Home & End keys) for Xamarin.forms uwp desktop application

Tags: xamarin.forms, keyboard-events, xamarin.uwp

I have tried to using "KeyboardDeliveryInterceptor" class using Dependency Service but was unable to achieve the result since it is disabling whole keyboard.

Reference for "KeyboardDeliveryInterceptor" : [Disable keyboard interaction with UWP app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54608597/disable-keyboard-interaction-with-uwp-app).

Answer (score 0):

> disable a specific hardware keyboard keys(e.g. Home & End keys) for Xamarin.forms uwp desktop application

For your requirement, you could handle [`PreviewKeyDown`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.previewkeydown) of current content then determine <kbd>Home</kbd> key pressed set `e.Handled = true` that could disable Home key pressed.

```
    class KBDInterceptorimplement : IKBDInterceptor
    {
        public void DisableTabKey()
        {
            Window.Current.Content.PreviewKeyDown += Content_PreviewKeyDown;
    
        }
    
        private void Content_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = e.Key == VirtualKey.Home ? true : false;
          
        }
    }
```